# Using the generic type 'IdentityUserRole<TKey>' requires 1 type arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Why do I get this error: "Using the generic type 'IdentityUserRole' requires 1 type arguments" when trying to rename the tables created using Identity. Please see my code below:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder){
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            //AspNetUsers -> User
            modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>()
                .ToTable("User");
            //AspNetRoles -> Role
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
                .ToTable("Role");
            //AspNetUserRoles -> UserRole
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
            //AspNetUserClaims -> UserClaim
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()
                .ToTable("UserClaim");
            //AspNetUserLogins -> UserLogin
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
                .ToTable("UserLogin");
        }
```

I do not get any error on the Entity AppUser and Entity IdentityRole but on the rest, I get the error. Please see image below:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that IdentityUserRole, IdentityuserClaim and IdentityuserLogin are generic classes too. Because the key for this table is specified by the generic type.

This is from the documentation

[IdentityUserLogin Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identityuserlogin-1?view=aspnetcore-1.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2)

And the implementation

[Github implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/IdentityUserLogin.cs)

So you have to do the following for example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("UserLogin");
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 glad I could help.

Comment: Got a question about it though. Why is it that sometimes I ron’t need to supply the string and it would qork?

Comment: @Ibanez1408 sorry I dont understand. Can you explain it please?

Comment: In my other application, I don’t have to put in the “<string>” and it works fine. But now I created another webapp, I have to put in this “<string>”?

Comment: Is your other application writen on the "old" asp.net?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187030/discussion-between-darem-and-ibanez1408).